# Как определить первую итерацию цикла в шаблоне Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть цикл `v-for`:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <span>первая</span> итерация
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `<span>` показывался только для первого элемента из `items`?

Answer (score 3):

в цикл можно добавить переменную `index` - что позволит определить индекс итерируемого елемента в массиве

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <span v-if="index === 0">первая</span> итерация
</div>
```

Это все описано в документации https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-v-for